# application pool crashes in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5

I have created a asp.net application with framework 4.0.

It has a sort of interview screen with so many questions on it with the paging.

It may have 1000 pages with 10 questions in each page.

when users are using this application screen randomly gets frozen and asks for window credentials.

We also keep getting error for the same application in error log as below:

> A process serving application pool 'appicationpoolname' suffered a
>   fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service.
>   The process id was '4768'. The data field contains the error number.

Not sure if both above error are related or not.

I have created a rule in debugdiag tool for application pool crash and that has generated a dump file.  The full call stack for the dump file is as below

```
Function     Arg 1     Arg 2     Arg 3     Arg 4   Source 
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+58     04242420     00000000     00000003     010ce504    
clr!Debugger::SendRawEvent+9b     010ce530     0000002f     0000015c     000012a0    
clr!Debugger::RaiseStartupNotification+48     6fa92811     00000001     01000000     00000000    
clr!Debugger::Startup+73     6fa92bf9     00000001     01000000     00000000    
clr!DoAdditionalPEChecks+e5     6fa92ac5     00000001     00000000     00000000    
clr!EEStartupHelper+5f4     00000000     6fa92a9d     00000001     00000000    
clr!EEStartup+52     00000000     6fa92a41     00000001     00000000    
clr!EnsureEEStarted+c4     00000000     6fa92f9d     014bb2c0     00000000    
clr!ClrCreateManagedInstance+41     708d4bb8     708d4ca8     010ceeb4     00000000    
webengine4!LegacyActivationShim::ClrCreateManagedInstance+61     708d4bb8     708d4ca8     010ceeb4     00c6e268    
webengine4!GetIsapiProcessHost+48     00c6e268     01c44e8c     6d8e0000     01c44e68    
webengine!GetIsapiProcessHost+d0     00c6e268     01c44e8c     00b907d8     00000000    
wbhst_pm+2e2a     01c4fed8     01c44e68     00000000     010cf56c    
wbhst_pm+335f     00b907d8     01c4fed8     01c4fdf0     010cf5e4    
wbhst_pm!GetProtocolManager+35     00b907d8     01c4fed8     00000000     00b90898    
w3wphost!AppHostInitialize+235e     7534415b     00000000     00000000     00000000    
w3wphost!AppHostInitialize+2698     010cf69c     708e199c     010cf618     00000001    
w3wphost!IPM_MESSAGE_PIPE::operator=+1c03     010cf69c     708e199c     00000001     708f1274    
iiscore!W3_SERVER::GetProtocolManagerCustomInterface+36     010cf69c     708e199c     00000001     708f1274    
webengine4!InitClrHost+186     708f1274     00000000     014c8004     00000400    
webengine4!CMgdEngGlobalModule::OnGlobalApplicationResolveModules+31     01c4efac     01c40330     010cf77c     7210a67a    
iiscore!VIRTUAL_MODULE::GlobalDoWork+152     00000400     01c4efac     01c4efa8     01c4efa8    
iiscore!W3_SERVER::GlobalNotify+98     00000400     01c4efac     00000000     72122f3a    
iiscore!W3_APPLICATION::ResolveModules+22     014cc280     00000000     014cc284     00000001    
iiscore!W3_APPLICATION::SetupNotificationContext+95     00000000     00000001     014cc284     014cc2e0    
iiscore!W3_CONTEXT::SetupStateMachinePhase2+2ab     014cc280     014cc284     00000000     72103358    
iiscore!W3_CONTEXT::SetupStateMachine+241     014cc284     014cc280     75341400     010cf894    
iiscore!W3_MAIN_CONTEXT::StartNotificationLoop+3f     014cc284     00000000     00c712a8     014cb828    
iiscore!W3_MAIN_CONTEXT::OnNewRequest+47     014cb828     014cb828     72a914e6     753413f0    
w3dt!UL_NATIVE_REQUEST::DoStateProcess+26     753413f0     010cf8c0     72a9154c     00000444    
w3dt!UL_NATIVE_REQUEST::DoWork+60     00000444     00000000     014cb82c     010cf8f8    
w3dt!OverlappedCompletionRoutine+1a     00000000     00000444     014cb82c     00c712b0    
w3tp!THREAD_POOL_DATA::ThreadPoolThread+89     00000000     00be7fd8     72cf0000     010cf924    
w3tp!THREAD_POOL_DATA::ThreadPoolThread+24     00c712a8     00000000     00000000     00be7fd8    
w3tp!THREAD_MANAGER::ThreadManagerThread+39     00be7fd8     010cf970     770f9ed2     00be7fd8    
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+12     00be7fd8     590a45de     00000000     00000000    
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+70     72cf1e5c     00be7fd8     ffffffff     771872ff    
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b     72cf1e5c     00be7fd8     00000000     00000000    

Exception Information
In W3WP__~1.DMP the assembly instruction at KERNELBASE!RaiseException+58 in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KERNELBASE.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused an unknown exception (0x04242420) on thread 5


I am not sure how to use this to fix the issue. I tried using Winddbg with .loadby sos mscorwks
command but it says invalid module mscorwks 

Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks,
MMC
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a first chance exception dump or a second chance exception dump ? When you created the rule in Debug Diagnostic tool, did you change something in the **Unconfigured first chance exceptions** section ?

Based on the stack it seems this is a first chance exception dump. Make sure that you change the Action time for un-configured first chance exceptions to NONE and then let the tool generate a second chance exception dump and that would be worth to look at.

If it generates one, analyze it using debugdiag and paste the stack and we can see why it is crashing